# SQL Left Join Behaving Weirdly

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

Can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong here?

I've got a table of timestamped data:

```
CREATE TABLE data_record (
    id UUID,
    t  TIMESTAMP,
    d  INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY(id, t)
);
```

I've got some data from some projects in that table, and now I'm trying to create a batch process to maintain one project where the data value (`d`) is the sum of the other projects.  To start, I'm trying to insert rows for the summary-project for all timestamps where the other projects have rows:

```
WITH source_ids AS (
    SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY['1e77b896-9e1b-11e7-a0db-f23c91e2b423'::uuid, '7dd37dd0-9e1a-11e7-a0db-f23c91e2b423'::uuid])
)
INSERT INTO data_record (id, t) (
     SELECT DISTINCT 'ab3b516e-acd7-11e7-a0db-f23c91e2b423'::uuid, d1.t
       FROM data_record d1
  LEFT JOIN data_record d2
         ON d1.t = d2.t
        AND d1.id IN (SELECT * FROM source_ids)
        AND d2.id = 'ab3b516e-acd7-11e7-a0db-f23c91e2b423'::uuid
      WHERE d2.t IS NULL;
```

As far as I can see, that should create a row with id `ab3b516e-acd7-11e7-a0db-f23c91e2b423` for every timestamp in a row with either of the IDs in `source_ids`.  But after executing that query, I then do this:

```
WITH source_ids AS (
    SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY['1e77b896-9e1b-11e7-a0db-f23c91e2b423'::uuid, '7dd37dd0-9e1a-11e7-a0db-f23c91e2b423'::uuid])
)
   SELECT COUNT(d1.t)
     FROM data_record d1
LEFT JOIN data_record d2
       ON d1.t = d2.t
      AND d1.id IN (SELECT * FROM source_ids)
      AND d2.id = 'ab3b516e-acd7-11e7-a0db-f23c91e2b423'
    WHERE d2.t IS NULL;
```

The `INSERT` query affected 28,237 rows; the SELECT query returns 55561 where I think it should return zero.

I guess there's something about the `AND d1.id IN (SELECT * FROM source_ids)` that's not working as it looks like it should, but what?

Comment: Move `AND d1.id IN (SELECT * FROM source_ids)
      AND d2.id = 'ab3b516e-acd7-11e7-a0db-f23c91e2b423'
    WHERE d2.t IS NULL;` to `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `LEFT JOIN`, filters on the *first* table should be in the `WHERE` clause.  Filters on the *second* in the `ON` clause.  Usually, the mistake is made on the filters on the second table.  Yours is on filters on the first table.

So:

```
WITH source_ids AS (
    SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY['1e77b896-9e1b-11e7-a0db-f23c91e2b423'::uuid, '7dd37dd0-9e1a-11e7-a0db-f23c91e2b423'::uuid])
)
INSERT INTO data_record (id, t) (
     SELECT DISTINCT 'ab3b516e-acd7-11e7-a0db-f23c91e2b423'::uuid, d1.t
     FROM data_record d1 LEFT JOIN data_record
          d2
          ON d1.t = d2.t AND
             d2.id = 'ab3b516e-acd7-11e7-a0db-f23c91e2b423'::uuid
      WHERE d2.t IS NULL AND d1.id IN (SELECT * FROM source_ids);
```

That still seems over-complicated to me.  I might suggest:

```
WITH . . . 
SELECT DISTINCT 'ab3b516e-acd7-11e7-a0db-f23c91e2b423'::uuid, dr.t
FROM (SELECT dr.*,
             COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE dr.id = 'ab3b516e-acd7-11e7-a0db-f23c91e2b423'::uuid) OVER (PARTITION BY t) as cnt
      FROM data_record dr
     ) dr
WHERE cnt = 0;
```

Depending on how the data and indexes are set up, your original version might be faster.